# Android AppCompatButton does look crazy in lower part of the screen

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-button, androidx

Con somebody explain the following behaviour in viepager2 und why the angle of the pressed button changes like this?

In the first image the first button is pressed.
In the second the 6th button (that looks crazy).

In the code there you can see my layout and below the style for the buttons.
I did change the buttons to material buttons, but this didn't solve the problem.

I don't know where this change of point of view/angle comes from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="17">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/rv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/style" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/style" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/style" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        style="@style/rv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/isearch_button0"
            style="@style/style" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/isearch_button1"
            style="@style/style" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/style" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            style="@style/style" />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

<style name="style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/templateTypeAnswer_male</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

[image: first image]
[image: seccond image]

Comment: show your XML code of this layout

Comment: I added the xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `style` you have set `backgroundTint` as transparent, thats not supported with shadow added by default to every `AppCompatButton`, thus you can see some glitches. if you need really transparent `Button` then use `background` attribute, but you will lose shadow (as there is no shadow under transparent objects in "material" world). if you need gray fuzzed background (aka. "only shadow") then use some custom `drawable` for this purpose, also set as `background` attribute. and then you may also set `StateListAnimator` as `null` - this attribute is "adding" shadow (not `background` or `backgroundTint`) and also an animation with `elevation` change when pressed. `null` will remove this feature (put below in your `style`)

```
<item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
```